# IBM Softlayer (Cloud Load Balancer + SSL OffLoad) ASP.NET too many redirects error

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a long running ASP.NET web application.

I have it connected to a IBM Cloud Load Balancer in a single server configuration (IIS) for a few weeks and am able to connect to the application just fine.

When I add a second (IIS) server to the load balancer configuration, I get a 'too many redirects error' for the site.

My research into the problem indicates the load balancer needs to pass a header X-Forwarded-Proto, and I need to add a rewrite rule to the web.config.

```html
<system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTPS rewrite behind ELB rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}{URL}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I've reached out to IBM support - Who are being as unhelpful as ever. They have simply suggested their IBM Cloud Load Balancer does not support the  X-Forwarded-Proto header, and I need to spend over 1K per month on a Netscaler.

Question 1.  The response from IBM just doesn't sound right to me, does anyone know enough to comment?

Question 2. Is there a programmatic way in ASP.NET to work around this issue of have a load balancer out front with SSL Offload and no X-Forwarded-Proto header?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is NO way to support if the front LB don't tell your the original protocol.
I'm currently working on IBM Cloud as well, it sucks sometimes such like this.